# Record Sound & Video form web client to flask server

Tags: python, flask, opencv, pyaudio

Im streaming a webcam form my web client back to the server with this gen "logic":

```
def gen():
   

 """Video streaming generator function."""
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    vid_format = 'MJPG'
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*vid_format)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('c:/test/output.avi',  fourcc, 10.0, (640,480))


    # Read until video is complete
    #sample_width, data = record()
    
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        
      # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, img = cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)


        if ret == True:

            out.write(img)
            frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()

            #frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            break
```

**And** would like to record voice at the same time with this:

```
def record():
    """
    Record a word or words from the microphone and
    return the data as an array of signed shorts.

    Normalizes the audio, trims silence from the
    start and end, and pads with 0.5 seconds of
    blank sound to make sure VLC et al can play
    it without getting chopped off.
    """
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=1, rate=RATE,
        input=True, output=True,
        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE)

    num_silent = 0
    snd_started = False

    r = array('h')

    while 1:
        # little endian, signed short
        snd_data = array('h', stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
        if byteorder == 'big':
            snd_data.byteswap()
        r.extend(snd_data)

        silent = is_silent(snd_data)

        if silent and snd_started:
            num_silent += 1
        elif not silent and not snd_started:
            snd_started = True

        if snd_started and num_silent > 30:
            break

    sample_width = p.get_sample_size(FORMAT)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    r = normalize(r)
    r = trim(r)
    r = add_silence(r, 0.5)
    return sample_width, r
```

**As** i see it, the only way to do both simultaneously is to run the sound recording in a different thread.

is this the right way or is there something more 'structured' or elegant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No multithreading here (obviously ):

```
def gen():
"""Video streaming generator function."""
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vid_format = 'MJPG'
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*vid_format)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('c:/test/output.avi',  fourcc, 24.0, (640,480))


# Read until video is complete
#sample_width, data = record()


"""
Record a word or words from the microphone and
return the data as an array of signed shorts.

Normalizes the audio, trims silence from the
start and end, and pads with 0.5 seconds of
blank sound to make sure VLC et al can play
it without getting chopped off.
"""
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=1, rate=RATE,
                input=True, output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE)

num_silent = 0
snd_started = False

r = array('h')

# little endian, signed short


#silent = is_silent(snd_data)


#return sample_width, r

while cap.isOpened():

  # Capture frame-by-frame
    try:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)

        snd_data = array('h', stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
        if byteorder == 'big':
            snd_data.byteswap()
        r.extend(snd_data)
        #r.extend(snd_data)

        if ret == True:

            out.write(img)
            frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()

            #frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

            #time.sleep(0.1)
            #print('true ret')
    except:

        sample_width = p.get_sample_size(FORMAT)
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()

        r = normalize(r)
        r = trim(r)
        r = add_silence(r, 0.5)

        sample_width, data = sample_width, r
        data = pack('<' + ('h' * len(data)), *data)

        wf = wave.open('c:/test/my_wav.wav', 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(sample_width)
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(data)
        wf.close()
        break

#cap.release()
#out.release()
#data = pack('<' + ('h' * len(data)), *data)
```